# Python requests - getting 503 response

Tags: python, http, python-requests

When I'm trying to scrape `1337x.to` I get `response 503` (service unavailable).

This is my code:

```
headers = {
                        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0',
                        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
                        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
                        # 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
                        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                        # 'Cookie': '__cf_bm=8AWn5cgl3wrLk8I2mbjcWF2hZo6yTMkQVbABnjiu06A-1662900329-0-AbK6GqFf8nWKuLYRCwJ5Ihk6+gS1Q9KumHHO7SoJPYtnpuFG1l4gJHnYw/L+r+lApFRAVgw7JOQNIfhdfo64/GN1+O7RrjVep7rS0515TiUA1kNuExIIavYFcsgHBwQcqQ==',
                        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
                        'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
                        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
                        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
                        'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
                    }

response = requests.get('https://1337x.to/popular-movies', headers=headers)
```

I tried without headers as well, but got the same result.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get('https://1337x.to/popular-movies')
>>> response
<Response [200]>
```

I get the above result. The only reason I see is you probably made too many requests(or their website was actually down). As a rule of thumb always have some cooling period between subsequent requests when scraping a website.

1. That is the responsible thing to do so you don't disturb the performance of the given website.
2. Your IP won't be blocked if any such WAF rule is present on the website's server.